# How can I convert this Python2.x code to Python3.x?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

```
  File "gridworld.py", line 19, in <module>
    import util
  File "/home/user/Desktop/reinforcement/util.py", line 23
    fixedState = (3, 2147483648L, 507801126L, 683453281L, 310439348L, 2597246090L, \
                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

```
class FixedRandom:
    def __init__(self):
        fixedState = (3, (2147483648L, 507801126L, 683453281L, 310439348L, 2597246090L, \
            2209084787L, 2267831527L, 979920060L, 3098657677L, 37650879L, 807947081L, 3974896263L, \
            881243242L, 3100634921L, 1334775171L, 3965168385L, 746264660L, 4074750168L, 500078808L, \
            776561771L, 702988163L, 1636311725L, 2559226045L, 157578202L, 2498342920L, 2794591496L, \
            4130598723L, 496985844L, 2944563015L, 3731321600L, 3514814613L, 3362575829L, 3038768745L, \
            2206497038L, 1108748846L, 1317460727L, 3134077628L, 988312410L, 1674063516L, 746456451L, \
            3958482413L, 1857117812L, 708750586L, 1583423339L, 3466495450L, 1536929345L, 1137240525L, \
            3875025632L, 2466137587L, 1235845595L, 4214575620L, 3792516855L, 657994358L, 1241843248L, \
            1695651859L, 3678946666L, 1929922113L, 2351044952L, 2317810202L, 2039319015L, 460787996L, \
            3654096216L, 4068721415L, 1814163703L, 2904112444L, 1386111013L, 574629867L, 2654529343L, \
            3833135042L, 2725328455L, 552431551L, 4006991378L, 1331562057L, 3710134542L, 303171486L, \
            1203231078L, 2670768975L, 54570816L, 2679609001L, 578983064L, 1271454725L, 3230871056L, \
            2496832891L, 2944938195L, 1608828728L, 367886575L, 2544708204L, 103775539L, 1912402393L, \
            1098482180L, 2738577070L, 3091646463L, 1505274463L, 2079416566L, 659100352L, 839995305L, \
            1696257633L, 274389836L, 3973303017L, 671127655L, 1061109122L, 517486945L, 1379749962L, \
            3421383928L, 3116950429L, 2165882425L, 2346928266L, 2892678711L, 2936066049L, 1316407868L, \
            2873411858L, 4279682888L, 2744351923L, 3290373816L, 1014377279L, 955200944L, 4220990860L, \
            2386098930L, 1772997650L, 3757346974L, 1621616438L, 2877097197L, 442116595L, 2010480266L, \
            2867861469L, 2955352695L, 605335967L, 2222936009L, 2067554933L, 4129906358L, 1519608541L, \
            1195006590L, 1942991038L, 2736562236L, 279162408L, 1415982909L, 4099901426L, 1732201505L, \
            2934657937L, 860563237L, 2479235483L, 3081651097L, 2244720867L, 3112631622L, 1636991639L, \
            3860393305L, 2312061927L, 48780114L, 1149090394L, 2643246550L, 1764050647L, 3836789087L, \
            3474859076L, 4237194338L, 1735191073L, 2150369208L, 92164394L, 756974036L, 2314453957L, \
            323969533L, 4267621035L, 283649842L, 810004843L, 727855536L, 1757827251L, 3334960421L, \
            3261035106L, 38417393L, 2660980472L, 1256633965L, 2184045390L, 811213141L, 2857482069L, \
            2237770878L, 3891003138L, 2787806886L, 2435192790L, 2249324662L, 3507764896L, 995388363L, \
            856944153L, 619213904L, 3233967826L, 3703465555L, 3286531781L, 3863193356L, 2992340714L, \
            413696855L, 3865185632L, 1704163171L, 3043634452L, 2225424707L, 2199018022L, 3506117517L, \
            3311559776L, 3374443561L, 1207829628L, 668793165L, 1822020716L, 2082656160L, 1160606415L, \
            3034757648L, 741703672L, 3094328738L, 459332691L, 2702383376L, 1610239915L, 4162939394L, \
            557861574L, 3805706338L, 3832520705L, 1248934879L, 3250424034L, 892335058L, 74323433L, \
            3209751608L, 3213220797L, 3444035873L, 3743886725L, 1783837251L, 610968664L, 580745246L, \
            4041979504L, 201684874L, 2673219253L, 1377283008L, 3497299167L, 2344209394L, 2304982920L, \
            3081403782L, 2599256854L, 3184475235L, 3373055826L, 695186388L, 2423332338L, 222864327L, \
            1258227992L, 3627871647L, 3487724980L, 4027953808L, 3053320360L, 533627073L, 3026232514L, \
            2340271949L, 867277230L, 868513116L, 2158535651L, 2487822909L, 3428235761L, 3067196046L, \
            3435119657L, 1908441839L, 788668797L, 3367703138L, 3317763187L, 908264443L, 2252100381L, \
            764223334L, 4127108988L, 384641349L, 3377374722L, 1263833251L, 1958694944L, 3847832657L, \
            1253909612L, 1096494446L, 555725445L, 2277045895L, 3340096504L, 1383318686L, 4234428127L, \
            1072582179L, 94169494L, 1064509968L, 2681151917L, 2681864920L, 734708852L, 1338914021L, \
            1270409500L, 1789469116L, 4191988204L, 1716329784L, 2213764829L, 3712538840L, 919910444L, \
            1318414447L, 3383806712L, 3054941722L, 3378649942L, 1205735655L, 1268136494L, 2214009444L, \
            2532395133L, 3232230447L, 230294038L, 342599089L, 772808141L, 4096882234L, 3146662953L, \
            2784264306L, 1860954704L, 2675279609L, 2984212876L, 2466966981L, 2627986059L, 2985545332L, \
            2578042598L, 1458940786L, 2944243755L, 3959506256L, 1509151382L, 325761900L, 942251521L, \
            4184289782L, 2756231555L, 3297811774L, 1169708099L, 3280524138L, 3805245319L, 3227360276L, \
            3199632491L, 2235795585L, 2865407118L, 36763651L, 2441503575L, 3314890374L, 1755526087L, \
            17915536L, 1196948233L, 949343045L, 3815841867L, 489007833L, 2654997597L, 2834744136L, \
            417688687L, 2843220846L, 85621843L, 747339336L, 2043645709L, 3520444394L, 1825470818L, \
            647778910L, 275904777L, 1249389189L, 3640887431L, 4200779599L, 323384601L, 3446088641L, \
            4049835786L, 1718989062L, 3563787136L, 44099190L, 3281263107L, 22910812L, 1826109246L, \
            745118154L, 3392171319L, 1571490704L, 354891067L, 815955642L, 1453450421L, 940015623L, \
            796817754L, 1260148619L, 3898237757L, 176670141L, 1870249326L, 3317738680L, 448918002L, \
            4059166594L, 2003827551L, 987091377L, 224855998L, 3520570137L, 789522610L, 2604445123L, \
            454472869L, 475688926L, 2990723466L, 523362238L, 3897608102L, 806637149L, 2642229586L, \
            2928614432L, 1564415411L, 1691381054L, 3816907227L, 4082581003L, 1895544448L, 3728217394L, \
            3214813157L, 4054301607L, 1882632454L, 2873728645L, 3694943071L, 1297991732L, 2101682438L, \
            3952579552L, 678650400L, 1391722293L, 478833748L, 2976468591L, 158586606L, 2576499787L, \
            662690848L, 3799889765L, 3328894692L, 2474578497L, 2383901391L, 1718193504L, 3003184595L, \
            3630561213L, 1929441113L, 3848238627L, 1594310094L, 3040359840L, 3051803867L, 2462788790L, \
            954409915L, 802581771L, 681703307L, 545982392L, 2738993819L, 8025358L, 2827719383L, \
            770471093L, 3484895980L, 3111306320L, 3900000891L, 2116916652L, 397746721L, 2087689510L, \
            721433935L, 1396088885L, 2751612384L, 1998988613L, 2135074843L, 2521131298L, 707009172L, \
            2398321482L, 688041159L, 2264560137L, 482388305L, 207864885L, 3735036991L, 3490348331L, \
            1963642811L, 3260224305L, 3493564223L, 1939428454L, 1128799656L, 1366012432L, 2858822447L, \
            1428147157L, 2261125391L, 1611208390L, 1134826333L, 2374102525L, 3833625209L, 2266397263L, \
            3189115077L, 770080230L, 2674657172L, 4280146640L, 3604531615L, 4235071805L, 3436987249L, \
            509704467L, 2582695198L, 4256268040L, 3391197562L, 1460642842L, 1617931012L, 457825497L, \
            1031452907L, 1330422862L, 4125947620L, 2280712485L, 431892090L, 2387410588L, 2061126784L, \
            896457479L, 3480499461L, 2488196663L, 4021103792L, 1877063114L, 2744470201L, 1046140599L, \
            2129952955L, 3583049218L, 4217723693L, 2720341743L, 820661843L, 1079873609L, 3360954200L, \
            3652304997L, 3335838575L, 2178810636L, 1908053374L, 4026721976L, 1793145418L, 476541615L, \
            973420250L, 515553040L, 919292001L, 2601786155L, 1685119450L, 3030170809L, 1590676150L, \
            1665099167L, 651151584L, 2077190587L, 957892642L, 646336572L, 2743719258L, 866169074L, \
            851118829L, 4225766285L, 963748226L, 799549420L, 1955032629L, 799460000L, 2425744063L, \
            2441291571L, 1928963772L, 528930629L, 2591962884L, 3495142819L, 1896021824L, 901320159L, \
            3181820243L, 843061941L, 3338628510L, 3782438992L, 9515330L, 1705797226L, 953535929L, \
            764833876L, 3202464965L, 2970244591L, 519154982L, 3390617541L, 566616744L, 3438031503L, \
            1853838297L, 170608755L, 1393728434L, 676900116L, 3184965776L, 1843100290L, 78995357L, \
            2227939888L, 3460264600L, 1745705055L, 1474086965L, 572796246L, 4081303004L, 882828851L, \
            1295445825L, 137639900L, 3304579600L, 2722437017L, 4093422709L, 273203373L, 2666507854L, \
            3998836510L, 493829981L, 1623949669L, 3482036755L, 3390023939L, 833233937L, 1639668730L, \
            1499455075L, 249728260L, 1210694006L, 3836497489L, 1551488720L, 3253074267L, 3388238003L, \
            2372035079L, 3945715164L, 2029501215L, 3362012634L, 2007375355L, 4074709820L, 631485888L, \
            3135015769L, 4273087084L, 3648076204L, 2739943601L, 1374020358L, 1760722448L, 3773939706L, \
            1313027823L, 1895251226L, 4224465911L, 421382535L, 1141067370L, 3660034846L, 3393185650L, \
            1850995280L, 1451917312L, 3841455409L, 3926840308L, 1397397252L, 2572864479L, 2500171350L, \
            3119920613L, 531400869L, 1626487579L, 1099320497L, 407414753L, 2438623324L, 99073255L, \
            3175491512L, 656431560L, 1153671785L, 236307875L, 2824738046L, 2320621382L, 892174056L, \
            230984053L, 719791226L, 2718891946L, 624L), None)
        self.random = random.Random()
        self.random.setstate(fixedState)

fixedState = (3, (2147483648L, 507801126L, 683453281L, 310439348L, 2597246090L, \
                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no trailing `L` needed to define an integer in Python3, which you are using in your code. You need to hence remove the trailing `L` from your integers and define that without that.

From the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html

> Integer literals no longer support a trailing l or L.

```
In [11]: a = 1                                                                                                                                                                                                               

In [12]: a = 1L                                                                                                                                                                                                              
  File "<ipython-input-12-61aa3f5b6495>", line 1
    a = 1L
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```